# Scanner - Dividir independentemente do número de colunas

Tags: java

```
public void lerFicheiro(){

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ficheiro);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            //quando numero de campos for igual a 4

            String designacaoAeronave = scanner.next();
            String capacidadeDeposito = scanner.next();
            String conteudoAtualDeposito = scanner.next();
            String consumo = scanner.next();

            System.out.println(designacaoAeronave);
            System.out.println(capacidadeDeposito);
            System.out.println(conteudoAtualDeposito);
            System.out.println(consumo);
            System.out.println("----");
        }
        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Tenho o seguinte ficheiro:

UPT100 100 50 5

CPT100 100 11 5 20

PPT100 100 5 5 120

Mas a primeira linha tem 4 variáveis a guardar e a 2ª e a 3ª linha tem 5 variáveis. Com o código que fiz só consigo fazer como está na imagem. Ou seja quando tem 5 palavras delimitadas por um espaço imprime como se fosse a designação da aeronave da anterior.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu nem entendi seu código, você está manipulando leitura de arquivo com Scanner?

Comment: Você já tentou usar nextLine() e fazer um split por espaço? Acho que aí fica mais fácil de vc atribuir as informações usando a quebra de linha como delimitador

Comment: sim isso mesmo.

Comment: @Sorack o nextLine vai ler a linha toda e o que eu quero é sempre que tem 5 "colunas" guardar 5 variáveis, sempre que tem 4 "colunas" guardar 4 variáveis

Comment: Tenta a solução que postei abaixo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique com o `nextLine` como no exemplo abaixo, assim você tem o controle da linha e com o `split` pode verificar quantas informações contém e decidir o que irá fazer com a informação:

```
public void lerFicheiro(){

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ficheiro);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String linha = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] informacoes = linha.split(" ");
            String novaInfo;

            String designacaoAeronave = informacoes[0];
            String capacidadeDeposito = informacoes[1];
            String conteudoAtualDeposito = informacoes[2];
            String consumo = informacoes[3];

            if (informacoes.length > 4) {
              novaInfo = informacoes[4];
            }

            System.out.println(designacaoAeronave);
            System.out.println(capacidadeDeposito);
            System.out.println(conteudoAtualDeposito);
            System.out.println(consumo);
            System.out.println("----");
        }
        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: esta solução está correta mas neste caso as variáveis tem dois nomes diferentes entende. Consegui resolver assim

Answer (score 1):

```
public void lerFicheiro(){

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ficheiro);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            //quando numero de campos for igual a 4

            String designacaoAeronave = scanner.next();
            int capacidadeDeposito = scanner.nextInt();
            int conteudoAtualDeposito = scanner.nextInt();
            int consumo = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println(designacaoAeronave);
            System.out.println(capacidadeDeposito);
            System.out.println(conteudoAtualDeposito);
            System.out.println(consumo);


            if(designacaoAeronave.startsWith("C")){                 //se for aviao de carga tem mais a tonelagem
                int tonelagem = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println(tonelagem);
            }

            if(designacaoAeronave.startsWith("P")){                 //se for aviao de passageiro tem mais a lotacao maxima
                int lotacaoMaxima = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println(lotacaoMaxima);
            }

        }
        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```